# SQL insert into table from tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

DB 1

```
Table A
+-----+--------+---------------+
|  ID |  Price | Date          |
+-----+--------+---------------+
|  1  |    100 |  2013.07.07   |
+-----+--------+---------------+

Table B
+------+--------+-------------+-------+
|  ID  | Name   | Description | Stock |
+------+--------+-------------+-------+
| A-ID |  Name1 |  Good       |   100 |
+------+--------+-------------+-------+
```

From these to these

```
Table C
+------+--------+---------------+--------+
|  ID  | Name   | Description   | Date   |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+
| A-ID | B-Name | B-Description | A-Date |
+------+--------+---------------+--------+

Table D
+-------+------+-------+----------+
|  D_ID | ID   | Meta  | MetaValue|
+-------+------+-------+----------+
|  1    | A-ID | price | A-Price  |
+-------+------+-------+----------+
|  2    | A-ID | stock | B-Stock  |
+-------+------+-------+----------+
```

How can fill the C and D table from A and B with one PhP code? xS
In Table A and Table B, I have 15.000~ row
For C need make for every item 1 row
for D need make for every item 30 row with different values (which are in Table A and Table B)

I'm fill the 'Table C' in this way

```
INSERT INTO DB1.C (Name, Description) 
SELECT b.Products_Name, b.Description
FROM DB1.B AS b
```

And

```
UPDATE DB1.C c, DB1.A a
SET c.Date=a.Date
WHERE c.ID=a.ID'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filling table C:

```
INSERT INTO C (ID, Name, Description, Date)
SELECT A.ID, B.Name, B.Description, A.Date
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

Filling table D would be two statements:

```
INSERT INTO D (ID, Meta, MetaValue) /*assuming here, that D_ID is auto_increment...*/
SELECT A.ID, 'price', Price
FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT A.ID, 'stock', B.Stock
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert into TableC

```
insert into TableCselect b.id,b.name,b.description,a.date 
from TableA a, TableB b 
where a.id = b.id
```

To insert into TableD

```
INSERT INTO TableD (ID,Meta, MetaValue) 
select id,'price',Price from TableA
Union
select id,'stock',Stock from TableB
```